# How to restrict someone to access my API directly using www.my-appspot-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer?

Tags: api, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created an app and some REST API on Google Appengine and deployed it to

`www.my-appspot-id.appspot.com`

I'm using Google Datastore to store my data and have created API's to access that data. 
However, i can access my API directly also using 
`www.my-appspot-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer` 
which means anyone can access them and can manipulate the data which i don't want.

How to restrict access so that nobody but some particular registered set of users can only use it?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?

Comment: See [Cloud Endpoints: Control who can execute API through API Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521424/cloud-endpoints-control-who-can-execute-api-through-api-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon [this tutorial](http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/) recently, might be of some help.

Comment: Per the Tutorial page (https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-5-7cece01570f#.16r0y1q3v) API Explorer can be accessed by anyone who Authenticates through their Google Account. They would also be able to submit/post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to authenticate your endpoints and authorize only some client id.
OAuth 2 authentication : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/auth
Allowed client ids and audience : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#allowed_client_ids_and_audiences

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question : **you can't**.

Google Cloud Endpoints is based on the explorer api: everybody will be able to navigate into your API, and **see** the differents methods available.

**BUT** if you add an authentication to your methods, the visitor will not be able to execute them.

Comment: Apparently, even if you have Authentication added to your entire API, anyone who authenticates through their Google Account (OAUTH2) would be able to execute them, even without any client id generated through Google Cloud Console.

https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-5-7cece01570f#.16r0y1q3v